# How to install WIC on Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise SP1?

Tags: wic

I am running on Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise SP1, however, I can't install Windows Imagging Component.

It says: `Setup could not find the update.inf file needed to update your system.`

I tried everything possible on the internet but it doesnt work. Please help me since I am trying to find a solution at least from the last 4-5 hours :/

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to use to 'install WIC'? WIC is included with Server 2008 R2 already. The only way to update to WIC on that platform is the [KB 2670838](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2670838) update which installs the [Windows 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj863687.aspx) version of WIC.